# AppEngine channel API: duplicate messages client side

Tags: google-app-engine, channel-api

I am trying to use the Channel API to push updates from server to the client. The flow is the user presses a button which triggers a server side action that generates a lot of logs. I want to display the logs to the user "in real time".

When I first load the page it I get all the messages, no problem. If I trigger the action a second time without refreshing the page in my browser, then all messages appear twice. Here is the set up portion of the channel that is tied to the page onLoad event. With resulting console logs I gathered that the onMessage() method is being invoked more than once when the page is not refreshed. Looks like I need to "kill" earlier sockets in some way, but could not find a way in the official documentation. Can someone point me in the right direction to get rid of the spurious messages?

```
// First fetch a token for the async communication channel and
// create the socket
$.post("/app/channels", {'op':'fetch', 'id' : nonce},
   function (data, status, xhr) {
       if (status == "success") {
       data = JSON.parse(data);
       token = data["token"];
       console.log("Cookie: " + get_mp_did() + "; token: " + token);
       var channel = new goog.appengine.Channel(token);
       var handler = {
           'onopen': onOpened,
           'onmessage': onMessage,
           'onerror': function() {
               $("#cmd_output").append('Channel error.<br/>');
           },
           'onclose': function() {
           $("#cmd_output").append('The end.<br/>');
           $.post("/app/channels", {'op':'clear'});
           }
       };
       var socket = channel.open(handler);
       socket.onopen = onOpened;
       socket.onmessage = onMessage;
       }
   });

onOpened = function() {
$("#cmd_output").empty();
};

onMessage = function(data) {
message = JSON.parse(data.data)['message'];
$("#cmd_output").append(message);
console.log('Got this sucker: ' + message);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your post and code correctly, the user clicks on a button which calls the `$.post()` function. The server code is responsible to create the channel in GAE as response to a `/app/channels` request. I think that your server in fact creates a new channel client ID / token with every subsequent request. Since the page is not reloaded, any subsequent request would add a new channel to this client. And all these channels would be still connected (hence, no page refresh).

I assume your server code has all channels associated to a user, and you send the message to a user utilizing all channels? Such pattern would result in this behavior. You can verify my assumption by clicking 3 or four times on the button with-out page refresh. The log output would be multiplied by the factor of 3 or 4.

I suggest, that you store the token in the client and on the server. Then make a modification to your client JS. If a channel is already created store the token value and provide it to any subsequent request to `/app/channels`. Modify the server so it will not create a new channel, if a token is provided with the request. If the token links to an existing valid channel, re-use the channel and return the same token in the response. You may need to add some more details for disconnected or expired channels, maybe also a cron-job to delete all expired channels after a while.

Comment: Hm, actually (a) the $.post() is done once on the client side after jquery onLoad(). (b) Specifically a new channel is not created every time the user presses a button. (c) I store the token and the id on the server side and resend the token if it is available (d) When sending messages I only send to a single token so it is baffling how messages are going to multiple channels

However every time the button is pressed without reload the messages do multiply. In other words I am seeing something that should not be the case... Hm. Perhaps it is some silly bug... let me investigate

Comment: After debugging the problem it turned out to be nothing related to the channels API. With every call I was just adding handlers to the logger and they were piling up without a page reload. But I am accepting Ani's answer as the right answer as it has all the stuff that needs to be checked if this behaviour was seen due to a Channels API problem